# Java EE, MySql and flush mode

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee

I understood that the method persist of EntityManager adds an Entity to the persistence context but does not commit data. But whatever i try, my entity is always commited. Can someone explain me how to configure a connection pool and persistence unit with mysql to avoid a commit when persist is called ? I would like to commit only when i call flush.

I use MySQL 5.6, Glassfish 4.1 and java 1.8.40

My pool is configured as follow :

< jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" name="mysqlDB" description="mysql db pool" transaction-isolation-level="serializable" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource"> 
      < property name="User" description="root" value="root"> 
      < property name="Password" value="manager"> 
      < property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydn?relaxAutoCommit=true"> 
    < /jdbc-connection-pool>

and my persistence unit is configured as follows :
    < persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    < provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider
    < jta-data-source>jdbc/mysql 
    < exclude-unlisted-classes>false 
    < properties>
        < property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="drop-and-create" /> 
        < property name="eclipselink.persistence-context.flush-mode"
                value="COMMIT" />
        < /properties>

Thanks in advance for any helps.

## After the first answer, i try to explain more precisely

I have two JSF forms, the goal is :
-  to create an entity TestEntity in the first form processing,
- then to call the mehtod persist of EntityManager with this first entity as parameter
- then to create an entity TestEntity2 in the second form processing, to link the seconde entity to the first one
- then to call the method refresh of EntityManager with this first entity as parameter and to call the flush method

The point is taht when i call refresh an exception is thrown saying that the entity is not in the persistence contexte.

JSFs call a session scoped managed bean which instantiates the entities, this session scoped managed bean calls a stateful EJB which calls a session scoped managed bean (@Named) TestPersistent and this TestPersistent which calls the Entity Manager. After the firts form the method save of TestPersistent is called, then after the second form, the method update of TestPersistent is called.
Here is the code of TestPersistent :

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class TestPersistent implements Serializable {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="test")
    EntityManager manager;

    public TestPersistent() {
       super();     
    }

    public void save(TestEntity entity){
        manager.persist(entity);
    }

    public void update(TestEntity entity) {
            manager.refresh(entity);
            manager.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing writing to the database, and committing the transaction. It's perfectly normal to write to the database several times during a transaction. Those changes however will be definitive, and visible to the other transactions, only after the transaction commits. If you rollback instead of committing, all the written changes will be canceled. Anyway, if you want an answer, you need to post the code of your test case, what you expect it to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and you're right i miss the point,

Comment: next. the whole code would be quite complex. <br/>

Comment: I try to add more detailed explanation in the question

Comment: it seems to be a question of transaction management by the container. I change the code, in the update metthod i do a find and merge and it does the job. But this is only a by pass ....

Comment: After somes times .. the book Java EE 7 essentials, A. Gupta, O'Reilly first edition, p 239 explains that each method call is a transaction. That would explain my question and problem. Is there a way to avoid a such transaction management ?